# How do I get the inner div to be vertically centered inside the containing div?

Tags: css

Here is my JSFiddle: [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rgmybd76/1/)

The problem I'm having is that I can't get my inner div with class `.modal-dialog` to be vertically centered inside its container with class `.modal-container`

I have set the `modal-container` to be a `table-cell`, with `vertical-align: middle` and given it a height of 100% but its not working as I want.

All I want is for the inner div to be vertically centered. The container `modal-container` has to be fixed or absolute positioned because its a modal that sits on top of the rest of the page content.

Here's the code (CSS then HTML):

```
.modal-container {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 270px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2000;
    background-color: #000;
    display: table-cell;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.modal-dialog {
    width: 210px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

<div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <form>
            <input name="EMail" type="email" placeholder="Email address" />
            <input name="Password" type="password" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot the CSS in your fiddle.

Comment: @j08691 oops! ive updated it now :)

Comment: Is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xw2tn8t6/?

Comment: @j08691, yep thats exactly what I wanted! The Y-scroll is working as well which is great.

Comment: OK I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can absolutely position the child div and use `top:0; right:0;bottom:0; left:0;` to center it:

```
.modal-dialog {
    width: 210px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid white;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xw2tn8t6/1/)**

Note also that I removed the display and vertical-align rules for the parent since they're not needed.

Answer (score 2):

j08691 has a perfectly good answer, but another option would be using `transform`.

## [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rgmybd76/3/)

**CSS**

Here's the important part we're adding:

```
.modal-dialog {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

We're using `transform` to slide it 50% of its height upwards, and 50% of its width left-wards.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution - using margin-top and relative or absolute positioning.  You make the negative margin half the height (thus, centering at 50% height).

```
.modal-dialog {
    width: 210px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid white;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -200px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Note, this works well only if you know the height (which it seems you do).